# I need a query result to display values different from what is present in the table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have table 'EMP' with column 'SerialNumber' and values as S001, S002, S003, S004...till S100.
I need the result to display SerialNumber as 001, 002, 003, 004..till 100.
How do I write this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it:

```
select substr(SerialNumber, 2) as SerialNumber
from emp
```

OR

```
select replace(SerialNumber, 'S', '') as SerialNumber
from emp
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c27f16ad5e49c95a96c9f6d6b2f6095a)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the function **REPLACE**:

```
REPLACE( target_column, bad_string, good_string)

Select REPLACE(SerialNumber, 'S', 'Serial Number ') from EMP;
```

Check this [page](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php) for how Replace works.